# Find the latest currency exchange rate from a range of cells, prior to a certain date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, libreoffice-calc

I have a sheet with some dates, and currency exchange rates on that date.

I have another sheet with some dates, and what I need is a function to return me the exchange rate on that day, or the latest date prior to that date.

So, something like this:

```
Sheet1
-----------------------
   |     A     |   B  |
-----------------------
 1 |2022-08-01 | 0.95 |
-----------------------
 2 |2022-07-25 | 0.91 |
-----------------------

Sheet2
----------------------------------------------------
   |     A     |                B                  |
----------------------------------------------------
 1 |2022-08-03 | Function which should return 0.95 |
----------------------------------------------------
 2 |2022-07-25 | Function which should return 0.91 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT**: This needs to work in Excel 2007 and LibreOffice Calc (without FILTER)

Answer (score 1):

vlookup does the job if your data is sorted.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$Sheet1.A1:B2,2,1)
```

sheet 2
[image: sheet 2]

sheet 1
[image: sheet 1]

Answer (score 0):

This function would handle it irrespective of the order,blanks, etc words in column a.

```
=index(Sheet1!B:B,match(Max(filter(Sheet1!A:A,isnumber(Sheet1!A:A)*(Sheet1!A:A<=A1))),Sheet1!A:A,0),1)
```

Comment: Any way of making this work with Excel 2007 / Libreoffice Calc (without Filter)?

Comment: @domaci_a_nas thanks seems like I already wasted enough time on this question since I answered it (exactly as it was presented) only to see you change the scope/requirements. What's to assume you won't do it again? So... good luck, but I've clearly already wasted my time, and won't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

1] Vlookup (if using in approx. Lookup) will return wrong result if Source table is unsorted as per the OP's example

So,

2] For Excel 2007 and unsored Source table , In `Sheet2, B1` formula copied down :

```
=SMALL(Sheet1!B$1:B$2,COUNTIF(Sheet1!A$1:A$2,"<="&A1))
```

**strong text**[image]

Comment: There was an error when there was no dates prior to selected date, so I expanded your expression a little: MAX(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A$1:A$2,"<="&A1), 1)

Comment: Sorry, I just checked and this doesn't work. Your method worked only because the dummy data was sorted in descending order as well.